# How to run apps on 3.0 Simulator right?

Tags: iphone

I created a new project from SDK 3.1 and OpenGL ES template. As you know this new template has ES 1.1 and ES 2.0 implementations. I wanna deal with ES 1.1 part first :) so I changed Base SDK in project settings to Simulator 3.0 and then I changed Active SDK in upper left corner of Xcode to "Simulator 3.0 - Debug". But when I start this sample project from template - it successfully initialize OpenGL ES 2.0 renderer in code and go to ES 2.0 part. I want to simulate old devices without OpenGL ES 2.0 and test 1.1 part. How can I do that without changing code?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers recieved from different sources are:

"The Simulator is not appropriate (nor has it ever been) for this kind of old-OS regression testing. Remember, the Simulator is not an emulator, has no OS, and doesn't accurately reflect the environment that your code will be running in"

and "The simulator can provide some behavioral differences based on OS. However, that is absolutely not a substitute for device testing. Additionally, iPhone OS 3.0 still supports OpenGL ES 2.0, and there is no way to disable that support in the simulator."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select "iPhone Simulator (3.0)" in "Active Executable" as well.

Also, you can change the firmware version of the simulator in Hardware -> Version.

Comment: My Active Executable already named "OpenGL Sample - iPhone Simulator 3.0". And simulator automatically set Hardware to 3.0 version if I select iPhone Simulator 3.0 - Debug.

Comment: Oops. Scratch that. Misread the question :) I guess you can change the code once by checking an environment variable (`getenv`) to determine which API to use, then you can select the API at runtime via Executable Info -> Arguments.