# Installing 2.0 sdk simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Few days back i upgrade to 10.6 and have to install everything from start. So i downloaded new sdk and install it but problem it has simulator above 3.0! But sometimes i have to test things in 2.0 onward, so how i can do this? How i can install 2.0, 2.2 and 2.2.1 simulator now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research to find the answer to my question ([link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036433/how-to-run-apps-on-3-0-simulator-right)) but it's sound similar. If you have access to Apple DevForums this is the link to thread **[Simulator 2.2.1 no longer available in SDK 3.2.1?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/134467#134467)**

The main point of this thread is "The Simulator is not appropriate (nor has it ever been) for this kind of old-OS regression testing. Remember, the Simulator is not an emulator, has no OS, and doesn't accurately reflect the environment that your code will be running in."

And there is no any workaround to install Simulator 2.2.1 and lower to Snow Leopard.

Comment: Thanks sergnsk. I think it give answer to me. Its just that some old written code cannot be tested! :@